# IE not opening window properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, window

So I did

```
  $('a.class').click(function(e){
    newWindow = window.open(link.attr('href'), 'name', "height=600,width=1000");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

But in IE it didn't open a new window, it uses the same window and it follows the link in the same window instead of doing nothing in the window and then open the link in a new window...

What should I do to make it open the link in a new window in IE (works in firefox, chrome)

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in IE7-9; it opens in a new tab from jsfiddle for me fine. Is there a reason you have to use window.open() or javascript at all?

Comment: I don't want a new tab...I need a new window, they're not the same, and it must be that width and height...it's requirements

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but i think `link.attr('href')` is not working as expected, replace with `jQuery(this).attr('href')` keyword.

```
newWindow = window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href'), 'name', "height=600,width=1000");
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your link

```
target="_blank"
```

you can also add it with Jquery.

Comment: no it needs to be a new window and not a new tab with that height, width setting as well having the window being able to be referenced in the variable

Comment: that is the html code I want it to be with that width and height and using those targets won't set the width and height